# Мобильная версия сайта

Tags: php, javascript, html

Добрый вечер. 
Есть сайт, который лежит на основном домене site.ru  и мобильная версия сайта, на m.site.ru

Как можно достаточно легко определить, сидит ли юзер с телефона?
Если сидит с телефона, то просто хочу переводить его на m.site.ru , с запоминанием в куках. Что посоветуете сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?i:midp|samsung|iphone|android)
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://m.site.ru/ [R=301]
```

Сделал так. Осталось добавить правильных агентов. Подскажите ;)

Comment: Есть такая штука: http://api.yandex.ru/detector/

p.s. У нас поровну уважения)

Comment: @Алексей Лобанов, спасибо за ссылку) Интересная штука. 
Да уж, рейтинг одинаковый) Подскажите как принять свой ответ за правильный?)